# How to make an AJAX work only if the user is logged in? -rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an app that the user can only click on a photo and save them if he is logged in, however he is still able to click on it and save them when logged out because the show page is similar.

If he is logged out though, the alert "picture was saved" still pops up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add some filter on your view, kind of mask and use cookie before showing there common screen. Once the user login remove the mask.

Comment: have you used devise for authentication?

Comment: If user is not logged in then you can disable the click on photo.

Comment: @SwapnilPatil I have not used devised for authentication, how does the syntax work for that in my javascript file?

Comment: If you're using your own custom authentication, you're largely on your own for debugging it. You may be able to formulate a narrower question (including code examples) if that's the case, but as it stands, your question is far too broad. You should look into using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication anyway; it's the defacto standard for Rails apps. There are other solutions, but it's a Solved Problem and considering how important and complicated authentication is, you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a conditional statement in the button or link that states only if the user is logged in is he or she allowed to save something. I don't have any code to use so I'll make up an example

```
<img>
  <%if user_logged_in%>
    <%= link_to "Save Picture", profile_picture_path(@profile)%>
  <% end %>
</img>
```

*Note: The user_logged_in is not a default helper method, I used it to better explain the example. You would need to write that method using sessions.

The problem is not in your AJAX call judging from your question, that seems to do exactly what your telling it to. It's actually the fact that you aren't preventing the non-logged in user saving a picture.

With that being said, how is a user saving a picture if they aren't logged in? Where and how is that picture being stored. Please upload some code next time.

Comment: I have a click on javascript method on an image that only works when the user is logged in, but the javascript alert "Picture added" still pops up even if the user is logged out, that is why. The picture is not being saved, but the alert pops up. How do I prevent the pop up alert

Comment: How does your controller look? It should send back a different response to success if the user isn't logged in. Can you put up some code?